# How to conditionally set an onClick attribute to component without having to repeat lines of nested code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working inside a functional React component and I'm trying to render a 'Card' component with a conditional onClick based on the member's typename. A card should be clickable if its typename is 'Bundle' or 'LegacyArticle'. Any other typename should not have an onClick property.

I'm having trouble finding an efficient way to apply an onClick to a card without having a conditional with a bunch of lines of repeated code, (the code that would essentially be nested children of the 'Card' component).

So far, I've been able to render it conditionally from a function. This allows my return statement to have better readability but there is still a big chunk of code that gets repeated, and I want to find a way to reduce that.

```
return (
 <div css={cards}>
      {members && members.map((member, index) => (
         renderCard(member, index)
       ))}
 </div>
);
```

```
  const renderCard = (member, index) => {
    const isClickable = member.__typename === 'Bundle' || member.__typename === 'LegacyArticle';
    if (isClickable) {
      return <Card key={index} css={card} onClick={() => onCardClick(member)}>
        {(member.__typename !== 'LessonSpark' &&
          schemas[member.__typename].image(member)) &&
          (<CardImage src={schemas[member.__typename].image(member)} />)}
        <CardBlock css={cardType}>
          {member.label || schemas[member.__typename].typename}
        </CardBlock>
        <CardBlock css={cardTitleStyle}>
          {_truncate(schemas[member.__typename].title(member), 60)}
        </CardBlock>
      </Card>
    } else {
      return <Card key={index} css={card}>
        {(member.__typename !== 'LessonSpark' &&
          schemas[member.__typename].image(member)) &&
          (<CardImage src={schemas[member.__typename].image(member)} />)}
        <CardBlock css={cardType}>
          {member.label || schemas[member.__typename].typename}
        </CardBlock>
        <CardBlock css={cardTitleStyle}>
          {_truncate(schemas[member.__typename].title(member), 60)}
        </CardBlock>
      </Card>
    }
  };
```

As you can see, `<Card>` has children nested, and it's a lot of lines of code being repeated when essentially, the only difference is one has an onClick and one doesn't.

Any ideas on how I could possibly reduce this code and find a clean way to apply an onClick conditionally?

Comment: Can you please add the complete code for the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `onClick` into an object and use prop spread.

```js
const renderCard = (member, index) => {
  const typename = member.__typename;
  const maybeOnClick = typename === 'Bundle' || typename === 'LegacyArticle' ?
    { onClick: () => onCardClick(member) } : {};
  const schema = schemas[typename];
  const image = schema.image(member);
  const cardContents = (typename !== 'LessonSpark' &&
            image) &&
            (<CardImage src={image} />);

  return (<Card key={index} css={card} {...maybeOnClick}>
    {cardContents}
    <CardBlock css={cardType}>
      {member.label || schema.typename}
    </CardBlock>
    <CardBlock css={cardTitleStyle}>
      {_truncate(schema.title(member), 60)}
    </CardBlock>
  </Card>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I needed something that would only apply the onClick to the component if it matched my condition. (Rather than check for condition inside the onClick itself.) This allowed me to reduce repeated code and solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can basically use DRY principle by only changing the unique / custom parts. So in this case the only difference i could see between the if and else statements was the onClick, so you can instead put the conditional there, if you want an onClick, in this case use a ternary or you could use `&&`.

```js
const renderCard = (member, index) => {
  const typename = member.__typename;
  const isClickable = typename === 'Bundle' || typename === 'LegacyArticle';
  const schema = schemas[typename];
  const image = schema.image(member);
  const cardContents = (typename !== 'LessonSpark' &&
            image) &&
            (<CardImage src={image} />);

  return (<Card key={index} css={card} onClick={ isClickable ? () => onCardClick(member) : undefined}>
    {cardContents}
    <CardBlock css={cardType}>
      {member.label || schema.typename}
    </CardBlock>
    <CardBlock css={cardTitleStyle}>
      {_truncate(schema.title(member), 60)}
    </CardBlock>
  </Card>);
}
```

In addition to that, you can save the values from function calls and from properties of objects so that a) the code is easier to read/follow, and b) the code is a bit more optimized, since it is not doing unnecessary extra function calls.

Comment: Hey George, thanks for your response. I actually forgot to mention I did try a ternary conditional within the onClick, but if we do that, the card on the UI still _acts_ like a link (hover, active, etc styles are applied if it has an onClick property).

Comment: that is a different question, you can add a class when not clickable and style it

Comment: @CarolinadelaFuente can you show us the code for Card please?

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is by adding the condition inside your Card onClick prop:

```
const isClickable = member.__typename === 'Bundle' || member.__typename === 'LegacyArticle';
return <Card key={index} css={card} onClick={isClickable ? () => onCardClick(member): null}>
  {(member.__typename !== 'LessonSpark' &&
    schemas[member.__typename].image(member)) &&
    (<CardImage src={schemas[member.__typename].image(member)} />)}
  <CardBlock css={cardType}>
    {member.label || schemas[member.__typename].typename}
  </CardBlock>
  <CardBlock css={cardTitleStyle}>
    {_truncate(schemas[member.__typename].title(member), 60)}
  </CardBlock>
</Card>
```